# YandexMapKit Ios, Как правильно использрвать класс YMKUserLocationLayer

Tags: ios, yandexmapkit

После обновления библиотеки YandexMap класс работа YMKUserLocationLayer была изменена и теперь проект не работает

```
YMKUserLocationLayer *userLocationLayer = self.yandexMapView.mapWindow.map.userLocationLayer;
```

ошибка: Property 'userLocationLayer' not found on object of type 'YMKMap *'

```
userLocationLayer.isEnabled = YES;
```

ошибка: Property 'isEnabled' not found on object of type 'YMKUserLocationLayer *'

Судя по описанию версий (3.4) во фреймворке изменили класс YMKUserLocationLayer (Возможность создавать UserLocationLayer с помощью MapKit, аналогично другим слоям.).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь правильно использовать этот класс.

Спасибо за уделенное внимание

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация теперь выглядит следующим образом:

```
YMKUserLocationLayer *userLocationLayer = [[YMKMapKit sharedInstance] createUserLocationLayerWithMapWindow:self.yandexMapView.mapWindow];
```

Остался вопрос как заменили enabled? (userLocationLayer.isEnabled)

Comment: А зачем вам проверять свойство isEnabled (которого нет), если предварительно сами создаёте этот слой? Создали - есть, не создали - нет... Или я чего-то не понимаю?